# How to run simultaneous commands in single terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal

I feel like this should be answered somewhere, but for the life of me I cannot find it so I figured I'd just ask...

I'm trying to run 2 commands in my terminal simultaneously, but I need them to run at the same time and both are ongoing foreground commands.

How can I do this?

For example:

`npm run serve` and `docker-compose up`.

I know I can run multiple "ending/stopping" commands with the single command line operators like `&&`,`;` or `||` but I need both to run at the same time in the same terminal window, using a single command, where a standard `cntrl + c` ends the action. Is this possible?

Comment: not going to happen in a single terminal - of course you can use something like `screen` (and other such utilities whose names escape me) that can actually allow you to run multiple "virtual terminals"  on the one terminal - split screen style - of course you can't "ctrl+c" to end both tasks - that's unpossible

Comment: Hmm...well that's unfortunate... I'll look at screen tomorrow, but I'm not sure at the moment if that is much better than using 2 terminal tabs

Comment: Technically, you can't have two _process groups_ in the foreground at the same time; for instance, in `{ cmd1 1>&3 3>&- | cmd2 0<&4 4<&-; } 3>&1 4<&0` both commands run in the foreground (in the same process group), but they share the file descriptors connected to their standard input/output and, in general, it looks like a horrible abuse of the pipe mechanism. Maybe you should ask about the broader issue you are facing -- to some extent this looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @ViaTech `better than using 2 terminal tabs` - of course it is .. you can see both outputs - I imagine that why you want to do this in the first place ... clearly it isn't to input into both at the same time

Answer (score 1):

You use a single `&`

```
command1 & command2 &
```

Each one of them will start in the **background**.

You might get away with having 2 tasks running with parallel:

```
parallel <<EOF
command1
command2
EOF
```

But that's not pure-bash. And I just checked and if you use `parallel`, if you kill the **group**, it kills the subprocesses started from parallel:

```
kill -- -pid-of-parallel
```

So if parallel has pid 54, you run:

```
kill -- -54
```

That should work.

Comment: The regular `&` puts the process in the BG. What is the single command I can run, like `cntrl + c` to kill those to restart?

Comment: If they are in the background? You use `fg` to put them in the foreground as you please (check `jobs` to know the tasks that are in the background) and then you can hit `ctrl + c`... or you can use `kill` to kill each process.

Comment: Also: `wait` to, well, wait for all the background processes to complete.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have two foreground processes in the same terminal at the same time but you can have multiple background processes.

As mentioned in other answers you can give a bash one-liner that will create two processes with each running in the background: 
**command1 & command2 &**

Output from both processes will come to the same terminal but you can't interact with either one because they are both in the background. To interact with one of them you can bring it to the foreground with '**fg**'. Then to put it back in the background you can use **Ctrl+Z** to pause the program followed by '**bg**' to allow the program to continue running in the background.

You can use the '**killall**' command to kill the processes rather than **Ctrl+C** since the processes are in the background. Or you can use the '**fg**' command to bring the processes back to the foreground then you can use **Ctrl+C** to kill them.

Use the '**jobs**' command to see what background processes are running in your shell. You can use '**fg %**' to bring a specific job to the foreground.

Comment: Warning: the `killall` command does different things on different OSes. On some, it kills processes matching a particular program name. On others, it kills *everything*. Please check the man page on your system to see what it does before using it.